# C++ Precise 44100Hz clock for real time audio synthesis

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio, midi

I am currently in the process of coding a MIDI synthesizer using my Raspberry Pi and its built-in UART input.

At some point in time, in order to enable live playback of MIDI input, I'll have to set up a sort of ring buffer to use with OpenAL, which should be pretty simple to do, just fill in a buffer, queue it in, wait for another buffer to be free to fill.

The problem I'm having right now is actually filling the buffers. I want to have a sample rate of 44100Hz, so CD quality. My plan is to have a clock running that calls the synthesizing function every tick, and writes a sample to memory based on the currently pressed keys, which I keep track of in another thread by listening to note on and note off events.

However, I'm noticing a problem here. Sleeping a thread for some time isn't precise at all, the thread is guaranteed to wake up after some time, but not exactly when that time has passed, so I don't really think that's a good way to go.

Is there some sort of tick generator that I could use that is precise enough for audio synthesis?

I know I'm probably reinventing the wheel here, as I could just grab a synthesizer and tweak to my own needs, but I'm interested in the whole process, so that's not quite an option.

---

I do realize it is possible that the whole writing a sample to memory every x is not a good idea either, but that's my best guess at the moment, so if you have any other suggestion, I'll be sure to take a look at it.

Comment: Can you wake often and get a high-precision reading on the current time? then act accordingly whether it is time to process some data or not? This type of design is typically more robust

Comment: @Jeffrey In that case, I might as well busy loop the problem away. I'm sure it'll work, but I'm also quite sure there is a much more elegant solution that hasn't come to my mind.

Comment: What you normally have is a chain of buffers in memory. You fill one or more buffers, and tell the hardware where they are in memory. The synthesizer hardware then reads data from those buffers at regular intervals, and makes sounds based on the data. Your code has to run at a regular interval only to the degree that it needs to ensure there's always at least one buffer of data available. At least with hardware I programmed directly, it could generate an interrupt when it was close to running out of data (so you responded to the interrupt by giving it another batch of data).

Comment: Sleeping at ten times the rate will sill have you sleeping most of the time. Less wasteful than busy waiting, you get on average only ten wake/check/sleep per cycke.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That should be easy to handle, I plan to have at least 3 buffers of raw audio, one of them should be being played at all times, once of them should be waiting to be played, and the other one should be being recorded on, the problem itself is getting the sample timing right.

Comment: @Jeffrey And the maximum lag would only be 1/10 of the clock period, so about 0.2 ms off. That could be a solution, but I have to have a way to know when I have to write a buffer and when I don't. This could be worked out though, surely.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems no lag. You should always be enough ahead in writing buffers that the next wake time (within reason) will no cause any additional lag. Basically aim to be a constant time ahead.

Comment: @Jeffrey So sleeping a constant amount of times for a constant amount of time between each sample? Or sleep for some amount of time as needed until we get close enough to the next sample window?

Comment: You never sleep for a predetermined time period; you just wait for a buffer to become available.

Comment: @CL. The thing is that I can't do anything with just a buffer, because I 
 have to generate raw sound data based on MIDI input. I'm not streaming an MP3 file, for example. I have to generate samples to put inside a buffer, and for that, I have to know when a sample should be generated, in this case 44100 times a second. Then, I can put those generated samples in a buffer when one is available, that's understood. The problem is the first part of the process.

Comment: Waking up a thread 44100 times a second is unrealistic, even on a "fast" computer (e.g. a gaming PC).  You'll have better luck e.g. waking up ~44.1 times per second, and generating 1000 additional samples on each wakeup.  (Spooling the 1000-sample buffers out to an audio output at 44100 samples per second is something best left to the dedicated audio hardware, which is designed to operate at that rate)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I guess this approach could end up working, I'll try experiment with it.

Comment: If you don't have hardware to do the buffering for you and handle the timing itself, you'll need some code at a driver level so it can respond to timers directly without having to wait for OS scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a high-performance timer.

Sleeping, as you observed is not accurate. Usually, the implementation will guarantee to sleep for at least the specified amount of time, but is allowed to sleep for longer.

Additionally, the typical system clock is not high-res enough.

If you use C++'11, a high performance clock comes standard. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/

That's the way I would go. If for some reason you can't use C++'11, there are options.

Windows exposes a high-performance clock through the Kernel32.dll, which provides these functions:
QueryPerformanceFrequency
QueryPerformanceCounter

Linux has sys/time.h, which gives you gettimeofday
A quick google search for gettimeofday might get you some better alternatives.

Check out my cross-platform high-performance timer on my bitbucket
https://bitbucket.org/akfreed/cppcrossplatform/src/e3f71e6d93de?at=default

Now you can poll the time in a tight loop.

This is very high precision. On my laptop, which is nothing special, (i3-5005U, dual 2GHz hyperthreaded) running Windows, i have a tick time of 513 nano. That is plenty of time to do do a function call in your 22.7 microsecond intervals. You could even do several atomic instructions and/or go out to main memory several times.

Comment: I'm working with C++11 so this is definitely a possibility. In fact, it hadn't occurred to me to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. I guess this isn't better than busy looping the problem out of existence, but it shouldn't matter as the only thing I'm really gonna be doing is synthesizing audio, playing it and listening for MIDI input.

Comment: You can yield() instead of spinning until you only have a fraction of time left. However, you have to test to make sure you don't ever miss your appointment due to scheduling woes. On my laptop, I stopped yielding when the timer got below 1 millisecond. 

You're going to be pushing your raspberry pi a little bit... If you're having trouble keeping your appointments, you might try putting everything on 1 thread.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers and comments already given, read up on hard real-time in Linux. In particular, read up on the relatively new SCHED_DEADLINE scheduler and also Ingo Molnar's real-time patchset, of which 80% resides in the mainstream kernel.

Comment: I'll take a look at this, since it looks like a useful tool to know about.

Comment: Also, an additional note - if you do anything related to timekeeping on a network, take a look at hardware timestamping in off-the-shelf NICs like the Intel i210 and i350. That is really useful for timing network events independent of any delays for packets to go from a user process through kernel and onto the net.